Adding MFormats SDK to dll cpp project compilation error
I am trying to add the MFormats SDK to my dll project (Logic).
There is no .lib folder (only DLLs). I read that I should do it with a manifest file.
So I took the manifest from the SDK and changed it to Logic.dll.manifest.
But I was not sure where should I put it, and where should I place the SDK dllls.
Should it be in ..\Logic\x64\Debug or ..\Logic\Logic\x64\Debug ? [I tried both but it still did not work did clean  + rebuild]
2. Changed the linker to it:

3. changed the include :



Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

You want #include "MFormats.h" using " ", not < >

Those are compilation errors, they have nothing to do with your manifest file.

I changed to #include "MFormats.h" but still get these errors
